# How to turn responseText into image from sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, image, sharepoint, xmlhttprequest, base64

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to get image from a sharepoint library. But failed at the point of converting a weird string like

> ����JFIFS���E������..

back to image.

I managed to get a URL of my sharepoint files that when i put it in the browser, it will automatically download the image. I have also obtained the accessToken to gain permission to the files.

I tried to use base64 encoder from external script to convert the responseText and failed to display as image. Btw, the `window.atob()` or `window.btoa()` doesn't seems to do anything for my responseText.

I am not sure what kind of format i received from the responseText to be dealt with. Because i tried manually converting the image to base64 for testing, which begin like this

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wB..

. However, the string i got from using the the base64encoder i found online start like this

> /f39/QAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD9/QBDAAs..

```
<div><img id="imgplaceholder" alt="place here"/></div>
<script>
var url =...;
var accessToken = ...;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json; odata=verbose");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var data = xhr.responseText;
        //or var data = base64Encode(data);
        document.getElementById("imgplaceholder").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
    }else{
        alert(xhr.status + ":\n " + xhr.responseText);
    }
} 
</script>
```

I expect the image to be displayed in the , but nothing happens. I have tried using ajax too, but noting works. Please can someone help me?

I was following this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231251/fetch-and-display-image-from-sharepoint-list-javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you show us what your data looks like that would help. Of course, unless you're building an image with data, loading an image in this manner makes no sense. dataURLs are limited by some Browsers as well.

Comment: After following the preferred answer links I see that they are not using dataURLs at all. They're just getting Object property absolute paths.

Comment: @PHPglue When i was using the method in the link. i encountered a bunch of html code which i also can't turn that into image. So i started trying to find the base64 code of image.

Comment: `document.getElementById("imgplaceholder").src = data.d.results[0].Image.Url;`

Comment: @PHPglue Is this code for url like in the link or the url i'm using? Because my url is a "directly downloading the image" kind of url.

Comment: Probably because your Browser does not support that mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below script would be helpful for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function Uint8ToBase64(u8Arr) {
        var CHUNK_SIZE = 0x8000; //arbitrary number
        var index = 0;
        var length = u8Arr.length;
        var result = '';
        var slice;
        while (index < length) {
            slice = u8Arr.subarray(index, Math.min(index + CHUNK_SIZE, length));
            result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, slice);
            index += CHUNK_SIZE;
        }
        return btoa(result);
    }
    $(function () {
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/MyDoc/panda.jpg')/openbinarystream";
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        //Now set response type
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var sampleBytes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
                var imageBase64 = Uint8ToBase64(sampleBytes);
                document.getElementById("imgplaceholder").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageBase64;
            }
        })
        xhr.send();
    })

</script>
<div><img id="imgplaceholder" alt="place here" /></div>
```